# Why does this code not work? Delete consecutive duplicate entries in the array

Tags: c#, arrays

i have this code and it does not work. This code should delete every consecutive duplicate in the array but it does not work. It returns array in exact same format it was before. I had "Car", "Truck", "Truck", "Car" and got exact same result. I should get "Car", "Truck", "Car".

Both of the array Versions give the same result.

**Version 1:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == 0 || result[i - 1] != array[i])
    {
        result[i] = array[i]; 
    }
}
```

**Version 2:**

```
result[0] = array[0];
for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == 0 || result[i - 1] != array[i])
    {
        result[result.Length - i] = array[i]; 
    }
}
```

But the code below that uses array list works. Could someone enlighten me why this happened?

```
List<string> results = new List<string>(); 

foreach (string element in array)
{
    if (results.Count == 0 || results.Last() != element)
        results.Add(element);
}
```

Comment: That should be an answer.

Comment: Version 1 gives you an array of ["Car", "Truck", null, "Car"] not the same, but you need to take into account what the next index of the result array should be

Comment: Because an `ArrayList` is dynamic, so you're only adding items that you want. A normal array is static, so it starts out with all `null` values until you replace them. As @DanD mentioned, you have `result == {"Car", "Truck", null, "Car"};` after the loop.

Comment: Where do you assign result[i] in the first place?

Comment: @tetete Check the updated solution below.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. I tested this code. It will manipulate the same variable.

```
var myArray = new string[] { "Car", "Truck", "Truck", "Car" }.ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    if (myArray[i].Equals(myArray[i + 1]))
    {
        myArray.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```

You need to remove all null values from result array. Check updated versions of your code below.

```
var myArray = new string[] { "Car", "Truck", "Truck", "Car" };
var result = new string[myArray.Length];
```

**Version 1**

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == 0 || result[i - 1] != myArray[i])
    {
        result[i] = myArray[i];
    }
}
```

**Version 2**

```
result[0] = myArray[0];
for (int i = 1; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (result[i - 1] != myArray[i])
    {
        result[i] = myArray[i];
    }
}
```

Perform following after both your versions to remove null values.

```
result = result.Where(r => r != null).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

## Why version 1 and 2 Don't work

The reason your code examples don't work is you (presumably as the code isn't there) have a second array that gets initialized like this:

`var result = string[myArray.Length]`

So this is a bunch of strings with `default(string)` which is null.

You then loop all items in `myArray` and the check of `result[i] != myArray[i]` is always true unless `myArray[i]` is null.

I presume your logic is trying to simply create an array of **unique** items.

## One-line Solution

If so a very efficient and one-line way of doing that is:

```
var array = new[] { "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b" };
array = array.Distinct().ToArray();
```